# как отобразить содержимое файла в JS

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

Условно у нас есть текстовый файл в папке assets.
Как можно вывести в консоль содержимое файла. Создаю файл через Java код:

```java
String[] data = {"Текст №1", "Тексто №2"};
int index = indexFromJS(Integer.parseInt(data[choose]));//П.С. переменная choose - тип int, значение которой получаем с БД
        String filename = "quickSave.ccs_ra_txt";

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("file:///android_asset/"+filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String indexString = String.valueOf(index); // Преобразуем целое число в строку
            outputStream.write(indexString.getBytes()); // Записываем массив байтов в файл
            outputStream.write(Integer.parseInt("\n")); // Записываем массив байтов в файл
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            r.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

А связываю данные с JS кодом этим методом

```
@JavascriptInterface
    private int indexFromJS(int value){
        choose = value;
        PreferenceConfig.setChoose(getApplicationContext(), choose);
        return value;
    }
```

И после этого в JS коде я вызываю метод indexFromJS таким образом:

```js
var workWithFile = Android.indexFromJS(i);
```

и как мне теперь обработать переменную workWithFile что бы она отобразила в консоле содержимое файла?

Comment: Так у вас метод ничего не возвращает, что вы хотите выводить

Comment: Значение возвращает... Или нет?

Comment: где у вас в методе indexFromJS  return, возвращающий значение?

Comment: @user453575457, это нужно в JS коде возвращать, а не в Java

Comment: Все равно не бьется - там где вы открываете файл и читаете его - вы должны вернуть содержимое. А так вы открываете, читаете и закрываете, результат идет никуда. В JS коде интерфес описан который не вохвращает результат чтения файла, а только имя файла которое вы в интервей и передали двумя строками выше

Comment: Вы буквально в js  возвращаете int - просто цифру, индекс файла, а не его содержимое или хотя бы строку какую то.

Comment: Более того - у вас indexFromJs это интерфейс в js,  в java коде он не имплеменирован - в java вы вызываете этот интерфейс, получаете из него индекс и все, дальше функционал - не реализация index from js - файл вы читаете просто .... вне этой функции